# virtualenv doesn't seem to work correctly on DigitalOcean droplet

Tags: python, virtualenv, digital-ocean, virtualenvwrapper

After creating the droplet and installing `virtualenv`, it is not able to able to differentiate between different environments.

i.e the same packages are appearing for different environments (`venv1` & `venv2` contain same packages exclusively installed for `venv1`.

Is there something that might be causing this?

Comment: The question is missing much context. Please note that DigitalOcean droplets are VMs, being abstracted for a lot of criteria and apps.

The information about OS, Python details, `virtualenv` details, how the setup is being created are missing, and a helpful answer requires them.

Comment: I've already used virtualenv on DigitalOcean droplets, it worked fine for me. Try `pip freeze` the droplet, outside of any venv, then create a new venv, `pip freeze` it, check it's current packages, then install some random package into your new venv that isnt on your Droplet neither on your venv and post the result to us.